# MeteorJS Password Account Reset Template not showing

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have password reset and that works fine, I can enter email and click send and got the email perfectly. However, the link in the email goes like this:

> http://localhost:3000/#/reset-password/6wOC1k8CeqPWrWltwbu-LvsoNh7R5SiUFu_RJb_sPEk

When I click it, it goes directly to my home page. I am not sure what to do or where to add the code below:

```
<template name="ResetPassword">
    {{#if resetPassword}}
    <form action="/reset-password"  id="resetPasswordForm" method="post">
        <input id="resetPasswordPassword" name="password" placeholder="New Password" type="password" >
        <input id="resetPasswordPasswordConfirm" name="password-confirm" placeholder="Confirm" type="password" >
        <input class="btn-submit" type="submit" value="Reset">
    </form>
    <!-- end #reset-password-form -->
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

In order for the reset password interface to show up. Currently I added the code above in a file called "resetpass.html" and then add the template name "ResetPassword" in the iron router but still not showing. Please help thank you.

Comment: by the way this the guide I followed:

http://www.meteorsnippets.com/blog/forgot-password-and-reset-password

Answer (score 0):

Ignore this question, I sorted it out. The the template need to be added in the home page in order for the reset password template to show up :)